# Dispatch an action from a component with data from a child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

So, I'm building a small app to learn some redux/react. The app includes a form that is built as a component with a Save button (and some more irrelevant code), and a child component that includes the form fields.

My intention is to update the app state, handled by redux, by dispatching a "SAVE" action (from the parent component) when clicking the "save" button, sending as payload the data from the fields inside the child component.

Is there a react-friendly way to do it?

Comment: why to do that just add the save button to form component so you access the form input values.

Comment: Do you have any code showing what you've tried so far?

Comment: I don't have access to the code right now, but I could include it later. I don't think it would add anything relevant though.

Comment: @adel I tried something like that (building just one component), but the way the app in general is built, I feel the Save button belongs to an outer section.

Comment: It looks like you want to know where to keep your state (https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html), but without an example of what've you've tried it's difficult to tell exactly what you're having trouble with/looking for

Comment: I see, thanks for the link! So the idea would be to keep the state of the form on the parent component, and feed that state and callback functions to the child. Then, the save action would then send the component's state as payload, right? I'll try it when I get home and add some more code the question, just in case. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If some portion of global state is shared between several components wrapped by common (parent) component, you may try to:

- bind child components event handlers to parent component callbacks
- store child components changes within parent's local state
- dispatch `SAVE` action to update global state

You may find the quick demo below:

```js
//dependencies
const { useState } = React,
      { render } = ReactDOM,
      { createStore } = Redux,
      { useDispatch, useSelector, Provider } = ReactRedux
      
//action, initial state, reducer, store
const SAVE_FEEDBACK = 'SAVE_FEEDBACK',
      initialState = {scores:[]},
      appReducer = (state=initialState, action) => {
        switch(action.type){
          case SAVE_FEEDBACK : {
            const {scores} = state,
                  {score} = action
            return {...state, scores:[...scores, score]}
          }
          default: return state
        }
      },
      store = createStore(appReducer)
      
//form component
const ScoreForm = ({onScoreInput, onNameInput}) => (
  <form>
    <select onChange={e => onScoreInput(e.target.value)}>
      <option value="" selected></option>
      <option value="awfull">awfull</option>
      <option value="awsome">awsome</option>
    </select>
    <input onKeyUp={e => onNameInput(e.target.value)} />
  </form>
)

//parent component
const MovieScore = () => {
  const [userScore, setScore] = useState(''),
        [userName, setName] = useState(''),
        dispatch = useDispatch(),
        userScores = useSelector(({scores}) => scores),
        handleScoreInput = score => setScore(score),
        handleNameInput = name => setName(name),
        onSave = () => dispatch({type: SAVE_FEEDBACK, score: {userName, userScore}})
  return (
    <div>
      <img 
        src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/uk/a/a4/Knockin.jpg" 
        style={{maxHeight:200}}
      />
      <ScoreForm 
        onScoreInput={handleScoreInput}
        onNameInput={handleNameInput}
       />
      <button onClick={onSave}>Save</button>
      <div>
        {userScores.map(({userScore,userName}) => <div>{userName} thinks, this movie is {userScore}</div>)}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

//wrap into Provider component
render (
  <Provider {...{store}}>
    <MovieScore />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.1.3/react-redux.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```